# Questions on limit of composition functions

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=A~,\qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{u\rightarrow A}g(u)=B~.$$

In which case is the following is true $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f(x))=B$$
Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true whenever $f$ is not constant in a neighborhood of $a$. This means when there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $f(x)\neq A$ for all $x\in (x-\delta ,x+\delta )\setminus \{a\}$.

### **Just to illustrate**

Take $$g(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}}(x)$$ (i.e. $g(0)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$). Take $$f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{[-1,1]^c}(x)$$ (i.e. the function that is $0$ on $(-1,1)$ and $1$ otherwise). Then $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0\quad \text{and}\quad \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0,$$ but $$\lim_{x\to 0}g\big(f(x)\big)=1\neq 0.$$